# Adjust width of Ext.Msg in Sencha touch

Tags: iphone, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-theming

I am trying to develop a mobile app using Sencha touch .I need to show a custom message box with 4 buttons.But i cannot change the with of message box,because of that only 3 buttons are visible in the message.please anyone help me to adjust the width of Message Box.Following is the code i am using

Ext.Msg.show({
         title : '',
         msg : '',
         width : 300,
         height : 300,

```
     buttons : [{
     itemId : 'A',
     text : 'A',
     ui : 'action',
     }, {
     itemId : 'B',
     text : 'B',
     ui : 'action'
     }, {
     itemId : 'C',
     text : 'C',
     ui : 'action'
     }, {
     itemId : 'D',
     text : 'D',
     ui : 'action'
     }, {
     itemId : 'E',
     text : 'E',
     ui : 'action'
     }, {
     itemId : 'F',
     text : 'F',
     ui : 'action'
     }]
     });
```

Thanks in advance  .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call `doComponentLayout()` after showing. i.e. `Ext.Msg.show(confObj).doComponentLayout();`

**Update**

http://jsfiddle.net/p5K4q/25/

Comment: Did you try setting it with class? To add the class to the container use the `cls` property of the configObject you pass to the show method.